# Set WooCommerce Price based on Custom Field and Custom Date (Not Working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a **reversed** "sale price" as in "`Future Price`" for single products in WooCommerce.

The general idea is to set a price (future price) and a start + end date.
Then, using the `woocommerce_product_get_price` filter, check if today is the same as the value of "future price start date" and if they are the same, change the product price.

When the future price end date has passed, restore the product price into whatever the regular price is.

**Problem is:** I am not getting any errors or notices or anything like that -- which means I am lost :)

To accomplish this whole thing, I have created a custom field (future price). I've also created the date fields. They are all saved and updated.

If anyone can help and give me tips / pointers, I would really appreciate it. This is my second (2 out of 3) school projects due within a week.

**This is my code in full:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'future_product_price', 20, 2 );
function future_product_price( $price, $product ) {

    if ( is_admin() ) return $price;

    $future_price       = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'future_price', true ); // future product price
    $future_start_date  = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_future_price_date_from', true ); // future product price start date
    $future_end_date    = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_future_price_date_to', true ); // future product price end date

    if ( ! empty( $future_price ) && ! empty( $future_start_date ) && ! empty( $future_end_date ) ) {

        $future_date_time   = (int) strtotime( $future_start_date ); // convert
        $now_time           = (int) strtotime("now"); // now in seconds

        // check if right now is the same day as the future price start date
        if ( $now_time == $future_start_date )

            // if they are the same, set the product price to the future price
            $price = $future_price;
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change "add_filter woocommerce_product_get_price" to "woocommerce_get_price_html" for display fuctre price and few small change in your future_product_price function :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'future_product_price', 20, 2 );
function future_product_price( $price, $product ) {

    if ( is_admin() ) return $price;

    $future_price       = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'future_price', true ); // future product price
    $future_start_date  = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_future_price_date_from', true ); // future product price start date
    $future_end_date    = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_future_price_date_to', true ); // future product price end date

    if ( ! empty( $future_price ) && ! empty( $future_start_date ) && ! empty( $future_end_date ) ) {

        $future_start = (int) strtotime( $future_start_date ); // convert
        $future_end   = (int) strtotime( $future_end_date ); // convert
        $now_time     = (int) strtotime(date('Y-m-d')); // now in seconds
        // check if right now is the same day as the future price start date
        if($future_start <= $now_time && $now_time <= $future_end) {
            // if they are the same, set the product price to the future price
            $price = $future_price;
        }
    }
    return $price;  
}
```

Add other functions for set future prices in a cart or checkout:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_alter_price_cart', 20, 2 );

function set_alter_price_cart( $cart ) {

if ( is_admin()) return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $price = $product->get_price();

        $future_price       = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'future_price', true ); // future product price
        $future_start_date  = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_future_price_date_from', true ); // future product price start date
        $future_end_date    = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_future_price_date_to', true ); // future product price end date

        if ( ! empty( $future_price ) && ! empty( $future_start_date ) && ! empty( $future_end_date ) ) {
            
            $future_start = (int) strtotime( $future_start_date ); // convert
            $future_end   = (int) strtotime( $future_end_date ); // convert
            $now_time     = (int) strtotime(date('Y-m-d')); // now in seconds
            // check if right now is the same day as the future price start date
            if($future_start <= $now_time && $now_time <= $future_end) {
                $price =  $future_price;
            }
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($price);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: is_admin() checks if you’re in WP admin, not if you’re logged in. I will review the other changes you mentioned.

Comment: Please explain more for better understanding

Comment: What do you need me to explain?

Comment: That works fine. Thanks for the help. Do you still need me to explain something?

Comment: Ok, thanks if everything working fine then no need to explain more.

Comment: I was just confused with the `if ( is_admin() )` comment since that only checks if you're in wp-admin, not logged in when on frontend.

All good now.

Comment: If any confusion just ignores it.

Comment: I think you should edit your answer to avoid confusion from other users.

Comment: Explanation : if ( is_admin() ) return $price; means if you are loggedin as  administration account, then function return $price, not will check to bellow condition for $future_price, but for customer or any other loggedin or for new user it will return $future_price. in sort only admin login can see actual price rest of will see $future_price for certain date range(future_start_date, future_end_date)

Comment: If in wp-admin, yes. It has nothing to do with being logged in as admin as such (as there might be other roles with the same capability). We have to return if in wp-admin. On frontend, no. This is why it might be confusing to other users. This is why it uses return for that if argument.

Comment: You can read more about it here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/

Again, I think you should edit your answer so that others do not get confused.

Comment: No confusion, you were wrong and you have edited your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I read and I know about is_admin(). I think some confusion between you and me, I think I can't explain more clearly.  if ( is_admin() ) return $price; means if login user is_admin then return $price ( function terminate/return just $price not move below for $future_price). Anyway, I have removed comments related to is_admin()  because the function is working fine so not matter anything else.

Comment: @LenaWeigler : If are you satisfy with my solution, please accept this answer.

Comment: No, it means that we do nothing if we're in the admin UI, hence the return for `is_admin()` which means do nothing. You should not confuse users with incorrect answers about user roles and logged in. I will accept the answer now since that has been removed.